# SUMIFS (or criteria using cell reference)

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a SUMIFS formula like this:

> =SUM(SUMIFS(DATA!A1: A5000", .. others conditions .., DATA!R1:R5000,"**{<=2017/06/05"," "}**) this works great, but we need
>   to replace the date with a cell reference.
>
> Something like this: "**{<=E12"," "}**.

We can't change SUMIFS since this is not allowed by the client.

Comment: How is it that your current formula "works great"? The range passed as the sum_range must comprise a single column - here you are passing a range (DATA!A1:Z5000) which comprises 26. As such, I cannot believe that your current formula does not return #VALUE!.

Comment: It was a typo, the first range is DATA!A1:A5000

Comment: Ok, thanks. And can you also just confirm that you're counting single spaces (" ") within the range DATA!R1:R5000. and not blanks/null strings ("")? I only ask since it seems unusual to have a column containing single spaces.

Comment: That's correct, the table data contains a single space in the cell, it has dates and " ". We are not able to update the information source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Concat the text with cell using `&`

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(DATA!A1:Z5000", ... , DATA!R1:R5000,"{<=" & E12 ," "})
```

Comment: No luck, we tried also {"<="  &  E12," "})), but the error "there's a problem with this formula" is shown. Is there a way to use CONCAT inside ?

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(DATA!A1:A5000,DATA!R1:R5000,CHOOSE({1,2},"<="&E12," ")))`

Regards